# Bind children to ListProperty

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have a **ListProperty** in my kivymd app that contains specific objects and I want to make widgets around this list.

As an example for simplicity, I have an **MDBoxLayout** in my app and I want to create **MDLabels** using the **strings** that are stored in this **ListProperty**.

The standard way is to loop through the list and create MDLabels based on the values, which is my current code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainApp(MDApp):
    texts = ListProperty(["DEF PATH: ~/Downloads", "PYTHON VERSION: 3.8.10", "PLATFORM: LINUX (KDE NEON)"])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True
    MDBoxLayout:
        id: box_texts
        orientation: "vertical"
        adaptive_height: True
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv

    # my current solution, which I am not happy with
    def on_start(self):
        for txt in self.texts:
            self.kv.ids.box_texts.add_widget(MDLabel(text=txt, size_hint_y=None, height=60))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

The problem is that this ListProperty constantly changes and multiple widgets access it, so for any change I have to manually update the widgets.

A hypothetical solution to my problem would be to use assign a **list comprehension** to the **children** property of the MDBoxLayout but in action for some reason it does not work (probably because children is an AliasProperty):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainApp(MDApp):
    texts = ListProperty(["DEF PATH: ~/Downloads", "PYTHON VERSION: 3.8.10", "PLATFORM: LINUX (KDE NEON)"])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
#:import MDLabel kivymd.uix.label.MDLabel
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True
    MDBoxLayout:
        id: box_texts
        orientation: "vertical"
        adaptive_height: True
        children: [MDLabel(text=txt) for txt in app.texts]
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Is there a way like my second solution that actually works?

Answer (score 0):

Since `texts` is a `Property` in `MainApp`, you can define a method in `MainApp` to build the children of the `MDBoxLayout` whenever the `texts` changes. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel


class MainApp(MDApp):
    texts = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
#:import MDLabel kivymd.uix.label.MDLabel
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True
    MDBoxLayout:
        id: box_texts
        orientation: "vertical"
        adaptive_height: True
''')
        self.texts = ["DEF PATH: ~/Downloads", "PYTHON VERSION: 3.8.10", "PLATFORM: LINUX (KDE NEON)"]

    def on_texts(self, app, new_list):
        box = self.kv.ids.box_texts
        box.clear_widgets()
        for item in new_list:
            box.add_widget(MDLabel(text=item))

    def build(self):
        return self.kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Note that the initial values of the `texts` is not assigned until after the `kv` is loaded so that the `on_texts()` method does not get called until the `kv` (and its `ids`) are loaded.